# Criar ficheiro .JSON com base no resultado da consulta SQL

Tags: php, json

Estou a tentar enviar os dados da minha base de dados para um ficheiro .json 
mas não estou a conseguir, pois cria o ficheiro e não aparece nada, só o array em branco.

o meu código é o seguinte:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","opcuaserver");
$query = "SELECT * FROM sensores (Timestamp, Metros, LM335, LM35)";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();
$data[$result] = array();


//format the data
$formattedData = json_encode($data);

//set the filename
$filename = 'basedadossensores.json';

//open or create the file
$handle = fopen($filename,'w+');

//write the data into the file
fwrite($handle,$formattedData);

//close the file
fclose($handle);

?>
```

e o resultado quando corro o código

```
{"Values->":[]}
```

Comment: O $result retornar o que ?

Comment: quero retornar os valores que estão na base de dados

Comment: sim mas agora ele está retornando o que ? se você rodar essa query diretamente no banco de dados ele retorna o que ?

Comment: neste momento quando rodo o ficheiro ela fica conectado na minha base de dados  e não mostra nada estou a tentar ir pela criação de um array mas acho que estou a enganar-me na programação dele

Comment: Deixa eu a query `SELECT * FROM sensores (Timestamp, Metros, LM335, LM35)` o que são esses Metros, LM335 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz ele percorrer o `$result` para gerar um vetor para que seja convertida pela função [`json_encode();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) trabalhe:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","opcuaserver");
$query = "SELECT Timestamp, Metros, LM335, LM35 FROM sensores";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if ($result) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,  MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $data[] = $row;
    }
} else  {
    echo "erro na query";
}

//format the data
$formattedData = json_encode($data);

//set the filename
$filename = 'basedadossensores.json';

//open or create the file
$handle = fopen($filename,'w+');

//write the data into the file
fwrite($handle,$formattedData);

//close the file
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Testa ai e vê se vai funcionar como necessita. eu segui essa [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351882/convert-mysqli-result-to-json).

Comment: o resultado foi este -> erro na query
Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\files\basesensores.php on line 14

Comment: Testa novamente eu acabei esquecendo do else, mas creio que o problema seja na sua consulta Sql, o que são esses valores aqui ? `(Timestamp, Metros, LM335, LM35)`

Comment: Timestamp é a hora e a data o resto são valores de sensores de temperatura e de proximidade

Comment: São as colunas da busca ? por exemplo Metros é uma coluna ?

Comment: o resultad é este -> Warning: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_ASSOC - assumed 'MYSQL_ASSOC' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\files\basesensores.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\files\basesensores.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\files\basesensores.php on line 14

Comment: sim são as colunas de busca

Comment: Editei a query para o que eu presumo que seja testa novamente,

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89335/discussion-between-bulfaitelo-and-sergio-nunes).